# Delete every record from mysql table where the date field is NOT in the future

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, date-math

I want to delete every row from the database where the Submission field is not in the future. The date is stored this way:

09/10/2013

So, in this example i want to delete this record, because its already expired. This is where i am:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `$table_name` WHERE `Submission` < NOW()");
```

Looks fine for me, but this query deletes everything from the table, not just rows in the past.

Comment: How do you know there are records in the future?

Comment: Store your dates properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That date is not a valid datetime. It's a string. You need to use [**`STR_TO_DATE()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it into a date before doing date math on it.

```
DELETE FROM `$table_name` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Submission`, '%m/%d/%Y') < NOW()
```

Comment: That is true. But this should point them in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, it was a simple string, works like a charm now!